# email validation un react js using useform

Tags: reactjs, email, gmail

Please, i want to make a signup form which accepts only gmail, yahoo and outlook email. I have encountered some issues with it. Please i need your help

this is the email input in the signup form

```
<label className="label"> Email </label>
            <input {...register("email",
                {required: "Please enter your Email",
                 // pattern: {
                 //     value: /^([\w.-]+)@(\[(\d{1, 3}\.){3}|(!gmail|yahoo|outlook)(([a-zA-Z\d-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|\d{1,3})(\]?)$/.test("email"),
                 //     message: "please enter a valid Email"
                 // }
                 onChange: (e) => {
                    handleEmail(e)
                 }
                }
                )}
            placeholder="Enter your Email"
            id="email"
            />
```

This is the method that handle the email

```
    const handleEmail=(e)=>{
        const value = e.target.value

        if(/^([\w.-]+)@(\[(\d{1, 3}\.){3}|(!gmail|yahoo|outlook)(([a-zA-Z\d-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|\d{1,3})(\]?)$/.test(value)){
            console.log("correct email")
        }else{
            console.log("please enter a valid Email")
        }
    }
```

Actually this is not working. want can you propose to me?

[I tried the following but it didn't worked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71660981/how-to-validate-only-working-emails-if-working-email-is-not-input-by-user-show)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with your code.

First, in the input element, you're passing the onChange function as part of the register function's configuration object. However, onChange should be a separate attribute of the input element. You can remove it from the register function's configuration.

Second, in the handleEmail function, you're using the test method on the regex directly, passing the string "email" instead of the actual value. To fix this, you should pass the value variable to the test method instead.

Here is the sample code you can use to achieve the specified requirement

```
<label className="label">Email</label>
<input
  {...register("email", {
    required: "Please enter your Email",
    // pattern: {
    //     value: /^([\w.-]+)@(\[(\d{1, 3}\.){3}|(!gmail|yahoo|outlook)(([a-zA-Z\d-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|\d{1,3})(\]?)$/.test("email"),
    //     message: "please enter a valid Email"
    // }
  })}
  placeholder="Enter your Email"
  id="email"
  onChange={handleEmail} // Move the onChange attribute here
/>

const handleEmail = (e) => {
  const value = e.target.value;

  if (
    /^([\w.-]+)@(\[(\d{1, 3}\.){3}|(!gmail|yahoo|outlook)(([a-zA-Z\d-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|\d{1,3})(\]?)$/.test(
      value
    )
  ) {
    console.log("correct email");
  } else {
    console.log("please enter a valid Email");
  }
};
```